# Iterate through all text files in a specific path and check if 2nd line has value

Tags: batch-file

Test which among the text files in a specific path contains value on its 2nd line and save the filenames to another text file using windows batch file.

This is what Ive done so far.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET COUNT=0

FOR %%A IN (C:\Users\mark.jim.a.mercado\Desktop\*.txt) DO ( 

ECHO %%A 
)
pause
```

It will list all the text files in the directory I used but when I tried to save the names of it to another text file (using the code below) only the name of the last text file will be saved.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET COUNT=0

FOR %%A IN (C:\Users\mark.jim.a.mercado\Desktop\*.txt) DO ( 

ECHO %%A @echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET COUNT=0

FOR %%A IN (C:\Users\mark.jim.a.mercado\Desktop\*.txt) DO ( 

ECHO %%A >C:\Users\mark.jim.a.mercado\Desktop\names.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: if we put the same effort in answering as you put into asking, you'll get just nonsense.

Comment: use correct [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html): `>` overwrites, `>>` appends.

Comment: I edited the question to indicate what I've done so far. Sorry for my first post as I am new to stack community. :)

Comment: Since you have still completely failed to provide any insight into your task and only tried to show us a method of listing file names to a text file. _(BTW not a good idea to write a text file to the same place as you're reading text files from)_. What value are you looking for on your second line? Or are you trying to detect those which have non-blank second lines?

Comment: Hi. I made some edits on the approach I am doing. Thanks to all your help. :)

Comment: It is actually a terrible idea to change the basic approach of a question, particularly when there are answers already. You should instead revert these changes and ask a new question concerning the new approach, because otherwise the current answers appear useless or wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to retrieve the second line of every text file is [input redirection `<`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
> ".\logfile.log" (
    for %%F in (".\*.txt") do (
        set "FILE=%%~F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        < "!FILE!" (
            for /L %%I in (1,1,2) do (
                set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
            )
            echo 2nd line of "!FILE!": "!LINE!"
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Since you do not tell us what you want to do with the second lines or how you want to filter them, it is quite impossible to provide more help...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it so much. I edited my question because I changed the approach I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what value to look for. IMO the easiest is to use findstr to number the lines and another piped findstr to filter for `:2:` aka second line (if existent)

---

Suppose there are three file: one.txt two.txt, three.txt with analogous number of lines and content:

```
> type *.txt
one.txt
one

two.txt
one
two

three.txt
one
two
three
```

This batch:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /N "^" *.txt ^|findstr ":2:"'
) Do Echo File:%%A Line:%%B Value:%%C
```

will outout:

```
File:two.txt Line:2 Value:two
File:three.txt Line:2 Value:two
```

Comment: I changed the approach that I am doing(see updates above). But your help means so much. Thanks.